# Error en Android con plugin Geolocation

Tags: angularjs, ionic, geolocalización, dominio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con *Ionic v1*, ademas estoy usando el plugin de *Cordova*, ***Geolocation***. El problema es que cuando la aplicacion corre en *Android* (*Ionic Run Android*) sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Only secure origins are allowed

Al trabajar en el navegador *Ionic Serve* no tengo ningún problema.

Answer (score 0):

En pleno 2019 y aun sigue presentando el error, en toda la investigación que hice para poder resolverlo fue que al momento de correr el comando

---

`ionic cordova run android --device -l`

---

Se me presentaba el error de la `Geolocalización`. La única forma para que no de error es corriendo el comando sin el `flag` `-l` de `livereload` ya que cuando se corre con ese flag, `ionic` monta el proyecto en un servidor `http` y para poder hacer uso de la `Geolozalización` tiene que ser desde un lugar seguro y solo se obtiene cuando ya sale la `app` a **producción**.

Espero que a alguien más le sea de ayuda esta respuesta, estaré atento a cualquier corrección o aporte que se haga.